# How to find Corelation between Multidimensional numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, correlation

I have a trained model. For this model, the input is a Numpy array with shape `(245,128,128,13)`. The output is a Numpy array with the shape `(245,128,128,1)`.

`245` represents number of samples.

`(128,128)` represents the image resolution.

`13` in input array represents the different parameters considered as input.

`1` in output array represents the model predicted output array.

Each sample consists of 13 `(128,128)` sized images in input array.

The output array consists of only one `(128,128)` sized image for each 245 samples.

Now I would like to find the correlation between each of the 13 parameters in input array with the output array. I require 13 values as the answer which represent the correlation values of these 13 parameters with the output value.

How do I find it.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just flatten the arrays before computing the correlation

```py
scipy.stats.stats.pearson(inp[:,:,:,5].flatten(), out.flatten())
```

for example computes pearson's correlation coefficient (and associated p-value) between 5th channel and output.

A bit overkill method could also be

```py
np.corrcoef([inp[:,:,:,i].flatten() for i in range(13)], out.flatten())
```

Which computes all 14×14 correlation coefficients between all 14 vectors that are the 13 inputs and the output. So, last column of that (or last line: it is symmetric) are the correlation coefficients between each input and output. It's overkill because it also computes, in addition to those 13 correlations you want, all the 13×12/2 = 78 correlation coefficient you didn't ask for between each input.